# Is there a scp/scftp folder monitoring application for windows?

Tags: untagged

I'm looking for a free application that runs as a service (i.e. no ui) and monitors a local folder (or a number of folders) for changes and uploads those changes to my remote web host by  ftp, sftp or scp.

I've downloaded several applications already that claim to do it but they're not quite what I want. I basically want the whole process to be automated once configured.

I find it hard to believe that software such as this doesn't already exist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about dedicated "monitoring service" but the functionality you need would be easily provided by this ftp sync script: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftpsync/ - its written in perl so you will probably need to get ActiveState's Perl interpreter: http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/
If you'll use built-in task scheduler (`at` command line tool) to run this script every few minutes it should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for essentially is a private / personal use of dropbox. Which leaves you two options I can think

1. Use dropbox. You are limited under the free account how much you can store, so it isn't all that good unless you want to spend the $$ for extra space.
2. Use [iFolder](http://www.ifolder.com/ifolder) , this seems to be a solution like dropbox, but you run it on  your own machines. I am currently looking at this as a solution for our office, so I don't have any actual experience, but from what I read, it should do what you are wanting.